# Login with Facebook: Bad Request. This combination of host and port requires TLS

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, spring-social-facebook

I have web application which use spring social facebook to login via favebook and register new account. I created Self signed certificate SSL and when I input https://localhost:8001/ its redirect me to my login page, but when I click on button "Login with Facebook" I got this error:

Status 400:

```
Bad Request
This combination of host and port requires TLS.
```

My social configuration looks like this:

ConnectorConfig class

```
@Configuration
public class ConnectorConfig {

private static final int HTTP_PORT = 80;
private static final int HTTPS_PORT = 443;
private static final String HTTP = "http";
private static final String USER_CONSTRAINT = "CONFIDENTIAL";

@Bean
public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
            securityConstraint.setUserConstraint(USER_CONSTRAINT);
            SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
            collection.addPattern("/*");
            securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
            context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
        }
    };
    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());
    return tomcat;
}

private Connector redirectConnector() {
    Connector connector = new Connector(
            TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
    connector.setScheme(HTTP);
    connector.setPort(HTTP_PORT);
    connector.setSecure(false);
    connector.setRedirectPort(HTTPS_PORT);
    return connector;
}
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
server.port=443

server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore/baeldung.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=123456
server.ssl.key-alias=baeldung

trust.store=classpath:keystore/baeldung.p12
trust.store.password=123456
```

[And picutre for settings in facebook for developers site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqBGH.png)

UPDATE: I set those properties for HTTP and HTTPS but when Spring Bott runs I got that ports 443 and 80 are already in use, but when I change to other port error is the same.

Anyone know how resolve this ? I think that from https://localhost:8001/login app redirect to http instead of https.

Comment: Did you solve it ? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: My second version was example from this site: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/ . Everything works from this website, but if you have frontend in React JS  I can tell you that better solution will be facebook-react-login npm component.